# Clear setTimeouts applied by class.each operation that creates timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm sorry the title might not make much sense. I'm not sure how to word what i'm  doing.

I have a class that I add to elements that uses HTML5 data attributes to setup a refresh timer. Here is the current code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.refresh').each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var url = element.data('url');
        var interval = element.data('interval');
        var preloader = element.data('show-loading');
        var globalPreloader = true;

        if (typeof preloader === 'undefined' || preloader === null) {
        }
        else if (preloader != 'global' && preloader != 'true') {
            globalPreloader = false;
        }

        (function(element, url, interval) {
            window.setInterval(function () {

                if (!globalPreloader)
                {
                    $('#' + preloader).show();
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "GET",
                    global: globalPreloader,
                    success: function (data) {
                        element.html(data);

                        if (!globalPreloader) {
                            $('#' + preloaderID).hide();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }, interval);
        })(element, url, interval);
    });
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

Now I have elements that a user can click on the 'window' which removes it.
These elements can be tired to a timer that was set by the above code.

Code used to remove the element

```
$(".btn-close").on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).closest("div.window").attr("id");

    if (typeof id === 'undefined' || id === null) {
    } else {
        $('#' + id).remove();
    }
});
```

I need to now kill the timers created for the elements removed.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear on how you clear them so I do them all here at the end.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.refresh').each(function () {
        var element = $(this);
        var url = element.data('url');
        var interval = element.data('interval');
        var showLoading = element.data('show-loading');
        var preloaderID = element.data('preloader-id');

        if (typeof showLoading === 'undefined' || showLoading === null) {
            showLoading = true;
        }

        (function (element, url, interval) {

            var timerid = window.setInterval(function () {

                if (showLoading) {
                    $('#' + preloaderID).show();
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "GET",
                    global: showLoading,
                    success: function (data) {
                        element.html(data);

                        if (showLoading) {
                            $('#' + preloaderID).hide();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }, interval);
            element.data("timerid",timerid );//add the timerid
        })(element, url, interval);
    });
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    $('.refresh').each(function () {
       var timerId = $(this).data("timerid");
       window.clearInterval(timerId);
    });
});
```

Example: remove timer on a click

```
$('.refresh').on('click', function () {
    var timerId = $(this).data("timerid");
    window.clearInterval(timerId);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.setInterval`returns a handle for the timeout. You can use that to stop the timeout:

```
var handle = window.setInterval(function() {
    window.clearInterval(handle);
}, 1000);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Since these are done and set in an each loop, what is the best way to track each one created that can be called back from another function to remove the timer?

Comment: Add the handle to a `data` attribute on the element?

Comment: The loop shouldn't matter, since you are within a closure, that can just handle it's own timeout handle. Otherwise you could remember the handle with the element it's used for (e.g. data attribute), or you can store reference to element and handle in a globally accessible array (though I would not recommend using global vars).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little demo of intervals and "interval assassins". It's a minimal example showing how you can clear intervals in a JavaScript-y way.

```js
$('.start').click(function() {
    var $parentRow = $(this).closest('tr')
    var $stop = $parentRow.find('.stop')
    var $val = $parentRow.children('.val')
    
    // interval
    var iid = setInterval(function() {
        $val.text(+$val.text() + 1)
    }, 10)
    console.log(`New Target: ${iid}`)
    
    // interval assassin
    $stop.click(function() {
        clearInterval(iid)
        console.log(`Interval[${iid}] has been assassinated.`)
        $(this).off('click')
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="start">Start</button></td>
        <td><button class="stop">Stop</button></td>
        <td class="val">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="start">Start</button></td>
        <td><button class="stop">Stop</button></td>
        <td class="val">0</td>
</table>
```

Just run the snippet to see a demo. Feel free to comment if you have any questions. You can set up multiple intervals by pressing start repeatedly and have them all be cleared at once with a single click of stop.